# Control when Reminders show in Notification Center

Tags: macos, notifications, reminders

In OSX 10.9.2 I have set reminders to show in the Notification Center. These are often for mundane tasks such as taking out the recycling. I want these tasks to appear maybe 10 mins before the due time - ideally I would like to have options the same way iCal alerts work.

However I can't find any options for when the reminders show up - they seem to show 24 hours in advance. This is confusing because for small tasks I often don't look at the time/date (where it says "tomorrow") and end up take out the recycling one day early!

Is there an option for this? I have tried setting iCal events aswell, and they also show 24 hours early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a specific time for a reminder: mouse over the entry in Reminders and a circled "i" for "Information" will appear, upon which you should click.  Then select the checkmark box, "Remind me: On a Day," and fill in the date and time for the reminder.

The Reminders functionality in OSX and iOS is minimal; Apple seems to have wanted to include a product to be able to say they did, but not one that actually competes with any of the third-party vendors, to avoid strangling the software ecosystem like Microsoft did with Outlook.  You might look at a third-party software package to meet your needs better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I agree, some of this stuff doesn't feel very well thought out or tested… I've set a repeating reminder and it shows '77 days ago' ie when I created it - don't need to see that!!